# "var" isn't working when in addEventListener or my code just executing first

Tags: javascript, discord, google-chrome-console

I was working on discord to test something about the bot commands. When I click on the command this code should be able to set tooltip and the parts in it but the code executes before the command one.

```
var commands = document.querySelectorAll(".commandName-1KhvGm.clickable-31pE3P")
var tooltip =  document.querySelector(".tooltip-1T4pLi")
var tooltipItem = document.querySelectorAll(".text-md-normal-2rFCH3")

commands.forEach(cmnd => {
    cmnd.addEventListener("click", () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            tooltip = document.querySelector(".tooltip-1T4pLi")  
            tooltipItem = tooltip.querySelectorAll(".text-md-normal-2rFCH3")
        }, 0)
    })
})
```

How can I fix it. I'm working on the chrome console rn.

I tried setTimeout, and other small things that comes to mind first

Comment: PSA: Consider using `let` instead of `var` here.

Comment: What is the intent behind reassigning variables to what appears to be the same thing you already set?

Comment: Since you never do anything to *read* from the variables, it isn't clear why you think it isn't working. You need to provide more detail. Please read [ask].

Comment: What "isn't working" about your code?  What are you expecting this code to *do* and why?

Comment: You tagged this [tag:google-chrome-console] which says "Use this tag when asking questions about the Console API and it's usage" but there's no sign of your code interacting with that API at all. Likewise, you've tagged this [tag:discord] and while you mention Discord, you question doesn't seem to have anything to do with its API (note also the description of that tag says " If asking about a specific API wrapper, please tag the library as well.")

Answer (score 0):

I have to make some assumptions here because your question is missing context.
It appears you want to store a reference to your tooltip and then assign to it.  You cannot do it like you have there because you are assigning the entire element into the variable.  That is ok but it only needs to be done once, and after you do so, it stays updated on its own.   I suggest you want to do something like this, although i can't test it.

```
 tooltip.innerHtml(newTooltipValue);
```

you need to read the value you want to set to the tooltip from the proper place in the event.  Note:   Using "let" here instead of var is a bad recommendation as you will lose scope out of the event.

See this link for more info:  Note:  I think they are available multi-language.  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp